# Do WPF custom user controls have enabled multi-touch manipulations by default

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multi-touch, awesomium

I'm creating Awesonium based multitouch browser. To do that I've created new user control using **Awesomium Web Control** and some additional controls. I've set this property :`IsManipulationEnabled="True"` 
Regarding to this article [with is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff898416.aspx), I've overrided this function:

```
protected override void OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    UIElement element = e.Source as UIElement;
    MatrixTransform xform =
        element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
    Matrix matrix = xform.Matrix;
    ManipulationDelta delta = e.DeltaManipulation;
    Point center = e.ManipulationOrigin;
    matrix.ScaleAt(
        delta.Scale.X, delta.Scale.Y, center.X, center.Y);
    matrix.RotateAt(
        delta.Rotation, center.X, center.Y);
    matrix.Translate(
        delta.Translation.X, delta.Translation.Y);
    xform.Matrix = matrix;
    e.Handled = true;
    base.OnManipulationDelta(e);
}
```

But manipulation does not work on Ui element. XAML code of user control:

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:awe="http://schemas.awesomium.com/winfx" x:Class="WebControlTouch.WebBrowser" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>

    <awe:WebControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="790" Name="_browser" AddressChanged="_browser_AddressChanged"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="_addressBar" Height="43" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335"/>
    <Button Content="Go!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.164,0.514" Height="43" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

What I should do to make manipulations working?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved this problem but in your UserControl you haven't set the below code
  `IsManipulationEnabled="True"` .

I don't know where you are setting this property but you need to set it in the UserControl tag